# How to dont show duplicate values in Mysql using Like operator?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is mysql query that i´m using.

```
SELECT distinct Emprego.title as title, Emprego.up as up, Emprego.datetime as datetime, Emprego.content as content, Category.name as category_name, Emprego.states as states, Emprego.id as id, User.nome as nome, Emprego.email as email FROM City, User , Category, Emprego, Type
    where
     Emprego.category_id=Category.id and Emprego.City_id=City.id and Emprego.type_id=Type.id and Type.id='$type'
     and  (Emprego.title LIKE '%$text%') or (Emprego.content like '%$text%') and Emprego.User_id= User.id
    order by datetime DESC
```

I´m getting duplicate rows with this query.

How to solve that???

This is the results:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Cozinheiro Madeira",
        "up": "1",
        "datetime": "2017-09-05 23:41:48",
        "content": "Cozinheiro na \nMadeira",
        "category_name": "Telecomunicações",
        "states": "2",
        "id": "12",
        "nome": "admin",
        "email": "admin@getal.con"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cozinheiro Madeira",
        "up": "1",
        "datetime": "2017-09-05 23:41:48",
        "content": "Cozinheiro na \r\nMadeira",
        "category_name": "Telecomunicações",
        "states": "2",
        "id": "16",
        "nome": "admin",
        "email": "admin@getal.con"
    }
]
```

Comment: You are *not* getting duplicate rows, because you have `select distinct`.  Please edit your question and show the results you are getting.  We can explain why they are not duplciates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff see the results and see if dont have "duplicates" lol .... i see duplicates...

Comment: You don't have duplicates. The "id" column is different in each row

Comment: @nzjoel i have... i have simple the results because was extend...

Comment: @GordonLinoff you answer dont work... have error in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You possibly have a problem because of the following:

```
(Emprego.title LIKE '%$text%') or (Emprego.content = '%$text%') and Emprego.User_id= User.id
```

Did you mean:

```
(Emprego.title LIKE '%$text%' or Emprego.content = '%$text%') and Emprego.User_id= User.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is so poorly written that it suggests showing you how to write a respectable SQL query.  *Never* use commas in the `JOIN` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT distinct e.title, e.up, e.datetime, e.content,
       c.name as category_name, e.states, e.id,
       u.nome as nome, e.email as email
FROM Category c JOIN
     Emprego e
     ON e.category_id = c.id JOIN
     City ci
     ON e.city_id = ci.id JOIN
     User u
     ON e.User_id = u.id JOIN 
     Type t
     ON e.type_id = t.id
WHERE e.title LIKE '%$text%' or e.content = '%$text%'
ORDER BY e.datetime DESC;
```

It is unclear whether or not `SELECT DISTINCT` is really needed.  This also fixes the problem in the `WHERE` clause, due to the precedence of the `AND` and `OR` operators.

Comment: Unknown column 'User.id' in 'on clause' ... dont work

Comment: @PauloRodrigues . . . There is no `user.id` in the `on` clause.